# Hypothesis testing of model parameters

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test

I am new to hypothesis testing and currently encounter a problem.

Given a model like this:

$$r_{w,t} = \alpha + e^{\beta v_t} + \epsilon_t$$

with data of both $r_{w,t}$ and $v_t$ and parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are estimated by nonlinear least squares.

> How can I perform hypothesis testing to test the hypothesis $H_0$ : $\alpha$ = 0 at the 5% level of significance?

I've read many materials related to hypothesis testing. I know that I have to state the null hypothesis and alternative hypothesis and I'm comfortable with stating the two hypothesis.

However, I have trouble with defining the test process, which is the test statistics and the test distributions. I know I have to define the test statistics and compare with target distribution to see if the result is significant. But I don't know how to do it with the above model.

Comment: What are you assuming about $\epsilon_t$? Presumably you are already estimating your parameters; if so, how?

Comment: @Glen_b thanks for your comment. I did not realize that the parameter estimating methods will be needed for defining the test. The parameters, $\alpha$ and $\beta$, are estimated using nonlinear least squares and $\epsilon_t$ is the error term of the model.

Comment: We're assuming constant-variance Gaussian errors? Or not?

Comment: Yes, constant-variance Gaussian errors